# Comparing two arrays and push in another array wrong position element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I got two arrays, both type string :

```
var correctAnswers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
```

and second :

```
var finalArray = ["0", "1", "4", "3", "5", "2"];
```

I would like to compare them and and if not match second with first to extract elements and push them in another array, like this :

```
finalArray = ["0", "1", "3"];

var toChange = ["4", "5", "2"];
```

Comment: Do you also want to store the index/position of the incorrect answers?

Comment: Nope, position doesnt need to be same. Just to push elements that doesnt match position and number with correctAnswer array into toChange array.

Comment: `Attempt` : 0% `Effort` : 0.1%

Comment: What about `"3"` in your example?

Comment: As i said...Sorry for dumb question @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: @user3459377 There is no dumb question. Just lazy questions.

Comment: @A.Wolff +1 , ill edit

Comment: I've been searching for an answer of this question enough, also i tried to implement solution that i've found...Nothing works. My morale goes down so i cant see the correct way now :(

Comment: @user3459377 How about posting what you tried (that didn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery `map` method too:

```
var toChange = $.map(finalArray, function(v, k){
    return correctAnswers[k] !== v ? v: null;
});

finalArray = $.map(finalArray, function(v, k){
    return correctAnswers[k] === v ? v: null;
});
```

### DEMO

Or using `array.prototype.filter()`:

```
var toChange = finalArray.filter(function(v, k){
    return correctAnswers[k] !== v;
});

finalArray = finalArray.filter(function(v, k){
    return correctAnswers[k] === v;
});
```

### filter DEMO

Comment: I've been running of using map, but it seems it work like a charm +1

Comment: @user3459377 this is jQuery map method. Using `array.prototype.map()` wouldn't work as expected here, maybe that was your issue here. Indeed, you should use filter() instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var toChange = [];
for (var i = finalArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (finalArray[i] !== correctAnswers[i]) {
        toChange.push(finalArray[i]);
        finalArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

The key to this is iterating *down* from the length to 0, rather than up from 0 to the length as usual. This is because `splice` changes the indexes of all the elements after the element being removed, so normal iteration would skip an element after each splice.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/XiozZe/NkM6s/

```
var correctAnswers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var finalArray = ["0", "1", "4", "3", "5", "2"];
var correctFinal = [];
var toChange = [];

for(var i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++){
    if(correctAnswers[i] === finalArray[i]){
        correctFinal[correctFinal.length] = finalArray[i];
    }
    else{
       toChange[toChange.length] = finalArray[i];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Also, great answer too!! Thanks for ur time

Answer (score 1):

First you've got to define your variables

```
// Define your variables
var correctAnswers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var answers     =    ["0", "1", "4", "3", "5", "2"];
var finalArray = [];
var toChange = [];
```

Then you create a loop, which loops over the Answers array.

```
// comparing them could be done with a simple loop
for (var i = 0; i<answers.length; i++) {
    if (correctAnswers[i] == answers[i]) { //if they're equal, push the value into the final array
        finalArray.push(answers[i]);
    } else { // if not, push them into the toChange array
        toChange.push(answers[i]);
    }
}
```

This will give you toChange = [0, 1, 3]
If you want toChange = [0, 1] you've got to change it to

```
toChange = answers.slice(0);

for (var i = 0; i<correctAnswers.length; i++) {
    if (correctAnswers[i] == Answers[i]) { //if they're equal, push the value into the final array and remove the first value from the toChange array
        finalArray.push(Answers[i]);
        toChange.shift();
    } else { // if not, break
        break;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2V9ea/6/)